# Using TFS, want to run a command line tool to perform obfuscation

Tags: command-line, tfs, build-process

First time using team explorer, and I want to add a build task that will run a command line tool to obfuscate the assembly.  This will one of the last tasks to be performed I assume.

How would I go about doing this using Team Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

We use Xenocode Postbuild.  To obfuscate, we use a custom build task we wrote in a DLL that we call from the build configuration in TFS.

So we [created a custom task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400767(VS.80).aspx) that wraps the PostBuild command-line.  We pass that task variables from an [MSBUILD target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx).  That target is part of the project file associated with our release build definition.